# HttpClientt.SendAsync doesnt wait/lock execution

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

```
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
var dataStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

This by idea should be awaited, but no matter what it do executions exists the method and returns to UI. Execution resumes when responses arrives, but by that time UI has already updated that execution finished, when in fact it hasn't.
All calling methods are awaited.

Initial method is not awaited by design `(Task.Run(() => StartDownload(selectedSchedules));` which starts UI method executing services that triggers httpclient, when that call finished UI should update with progress, but the second `httpClient.SendAsync`is executed, execution returns to UI

```
Task.Run(() => StartDownload(selectedSchedules)); //First call, initiated by a button

public async Task StartDownload(SchedulesList list)
{
    //var t = new Task(() => _scheduleServices.Download(list));
    //t.Start();
    //await t;
    await _scheduleServices.DownloadIwcfDb(list, UsbInfoModels);
}

public async Task Download(SchedulesList schedulesList)
{                         
    await DownloadDb(schedulesList);        
}

private async Task DownloadDb(SchedulesList schedulesList)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), ApiCallUrls.GetIwcfSchedules)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schedulesList), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        var httpResponseMessage= await httpClient.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var dataStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        using (Stream contentStream = dataStream, stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Directories.SomEDir, Directories.SomeFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Call Chain Added, irrelevant code removed from the methods

Comment: Was the method this ran in set to be async

Comment: please provide the source code for the calling function (the one using the `Task.Run()`)

Comment: @BenSteele yes, has to be to use httpclient , calling chain added

Comment: @FlorianMoser added full call chain, unnecessary code is emitted, so some methods look lightweight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're problem probably lies within your first call.

In your code you have:

```
Task.Run(()=>StartDownload(selectedSchedules)); //First call, initiated by a button
//I assume afterwards you update the ProgressBar or give some other progress feedback
```

What this does is: It calls `StartDownload` and **immediately** continues execution. All the other stuff (downloading etc) is then happening in the background. Remember that the method `StartDownload` does not block; it simply returns a `Task` object. If you do not `await` that `Task` object, the code will simply proceed.

I guess what you wanted is: Call `StartDownload`, wait for it to finish, then update the progress.

A quick solution would be to mark your event handler of the button with `async`, and then use `async` all the way. The method would look a bit like this:

```
private async void HandleEvent()
{
    await StartDownload();
    //update progress
}
```

I can recommend you this blog post from Stephen Cleary for an introduction to async-await: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Actually turns out my code works , I am 99% sure it was exiting before, must have not stepped through my latest changes properly, but I'll accept your answer as it would probably help in majority of cases. Though I was fairly certain I didn't need async event handler to wait my execution as execution gets awaited from within and updates UI along the chain ( that part was omitted as not related to actual execution)